# mysql join query with tables in two different databases

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a php app based on MySQL. I connect to the first database with

```
$conn1 = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "db1");
```

and then perform a query. How can I do the JOIN if table1 and table2 are located in 2 different databases (exemple $conn1 and $conn2) ?

```
$stmt = $conn1->prepare("SELECT a.var1, a.var2, a.var3, ...
                         FROM table1 a
                         JOIN table2 b //this is located on $conn2
                         ON a.var1 = b.var7
```

Comment: Are the two databases on the same server/database system, or on different servers? You can only join databases on the same connection/server.

Comment: the databases are on the same server (same harddisk)

Comment: If the two tables are on the same Database-Server, just other databases, you doesn't need two connections in php. Use Database.TableName. In your case ... FROM  db1.table1 a JOIN db2.table2 b ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the databases are on the same server (same harddisk)

You need only one connection, but the user you are using on the connection must have access on the both databases (or only on both tables).

In you query you must specify/append database names before each table.

Something like:

```
SELECT a.var1, a.var2, a.var3, ...
FROM database1.table1 a
JOIN database2.table2 b
```